# css problem with navigation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I use example 3 given in this page:

```
http://simple-navigation-demo.andischacke.com/
```

and I have a problem because when I open the main page (for example)

```
http://simple-navigation-demo.andischacke.com/
```

[image]

I get an empty div on the left instead of the content div filling the whole area.

On the other hand when I open a page from the menu (for example)

```
http://simple-navigation-demo.andischacke.com/books
```

[image]

Everything is just fine.

Can someone propose a solution? How can I completely remove the div in CSS if it does not contain anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of solutions; it depends on where you want your logic to be.  A pure CSS solution might be tricky; it might be easier to do this sort of thing in JS.

That said, try changing `#sub_navigation`'s `width` property to be a `max-width` instead. This way, it can still be set to `float:left`, but when there's no `ul` element inside it, it can collapse.

You might need to modify the width of your `content` div after that, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.